# CoreData - how to convert fetch results from AnyObject to custom object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to convert fetch results from AnyObject to custom class, so I can have access to properties of elements that return after fetching

I tried to cast, but it fails

[image]

How can I do that ?

Comment: You will need to typecast them. For instance If the object is foo, and my class is  'Custom'  and I can say let myCustom = foo as Custom.

Comment: I tried, you mean that ? https://s.mail.ru/59B5vtKZtVBG/img-2015-07-29-14-03-43.png

Comment: Well, you need to say as? [Question]  as already pointed by ciccioska.

Comment: include code and errors as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: if I add as? [Question] {..} it stops complaining but fetch requests returns nil

Comment: Try use also the second parameter of the executeFetchRequest(request, error: yourError) method and see why something goes wrong

Comment: I tryed, and it says - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. But when I fetch without casting it prints out all objects from DB without any error

Answer (score 0):

When you load data from fetchResultController can try this:

```
if let customObjects = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(NSFetchRequest...) as? [CustomObject]{
}
```

change `self.managedObjectContext` with your `NSManagedObjectContext`

Comment: complains about protocol https://s.mail.ru/59B5vtKZtVBG/img-2015-07-29-14-03-43.png